# Javascript not being executed from post-commit of remotipart

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, post, ruby-on-rails-3.1, respond-to

I'm a newb RoR programmer and I'm currently trying to make my js work after I upload a file using remotipart and submitting it with a POST request to the controller. Basically, after the button submit is clicked, the POST request is successfully sent but the parse_bond_file.js.erb is initiated as OTHER not as SCRIPT. Here is my code:

---upload.html.erb###

```
<%= form_for :parse_bond, :url => parse_bond_file_issuers_path, :html => { :multipart => true, :method => :post }, :remote => true do |f| %>
    <%= f.file_field :csv %>
    <%= f.submit 'Parse'%>
<% end %>
```

---issuer_controller.rb---

```
  def parse_bond_file
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

---parse_bond_file.js.erb---

```
alert('hello world!');
```

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find anything?

Answer (score 0):

With the latest remotipart, you need to wrap it in

```
<%= remotipart_response do %>
  console.log('hellow world!');
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this line into your app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```